# spark structured streaming exception while writing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting below error while wrting spark structured streaming dataframe -
please tell me where I am doing wrong while running this code-

here df is reading from s3://abc/testing location and I am writing this dataframe to different s3 location using spark streaming-

```
 val q = df  .writeStream
        .trigger(Trigger.Once)
        .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://abc/checkpoint")
        .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
           batchDF
            .write
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .parquet("s3://abc/demo")
        }.start()
      q.processAllAvailable()
      q.stop()
```

while running above code I get below error -

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Job aborted.
    === Streaming Query ===
    Identifier: [id = 82cae180-6190-499a-99ae, runId = 23aa9dca-c6ef-49ff-b860]
    Current Committed Offsets: {}
    Current Available Offsets: {FileStreamSource[s3://abc/testing]: {"logOffset":0}}
    
    Current State: ACTIVE
    Thread State: RUNNABLE
    
    Logical Plan:
    FileStreamSource[s3://abc/testing]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:379)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:269)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$3(SparkPlan.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:884)
    at line7d42fe70c8664871b443fdc5f6bbc35869.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$withCreateExtract$5(command-3858326:61)
    at line7d42fe70c8664871b443fdc5f6bbc35869.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$withCreateExtract$5$adapted(command-3858326:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:593)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:231)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.OneTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:269)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 31 tasks (4.0 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize 4.0 GiB.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2519)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2466)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2668)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2656)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2339)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2434)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.$anonfun$relationFuture$1(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$4(SQLExecution.scala:308)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$3(SQLExecution.scala:308)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$2(SQLExecution.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withOptimisticTransaction(SQLExecution.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:306)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Well considering that you're writing to S3, there could be problems with the connection, you can check that. But it seems to me like the main exception message is missing, you sure you posted the whole stack trace?

Comment: @Filip I added entire error message, if you can help me out

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please consider accepting it on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Total size of serialized results of 31 tasks (4.0 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize 4.0 GiB.` means when a executor is trying to send its result to driver, it exceeds `spark.driver.maxResultSize`. You can resolve it by increasing it till you get it to work, but it's not a recommendation if an executor is trying to send too much data.

Other thing that could cause this is that data is skewed, you should check how data is distributed on the worker nodes, possible scenario is that all data ends up on single node which causes huge input/output of data from single worker. In this case you can try to repartition your data to split the load between your workers which will be much better solution that increasing the limit.